# PySimpleGUI Listbox right click menu

Tags: python, listbox, right-click, pysimplegui

I am wondering, is it possible to make the right click menu work on the selected box in the list box?

Example of a right click menu

[image: example of a right click menu]

I have succeeded in making a right click menu for the entire list box by doing

```
layout = [
        [gui.Listbox(size=(35, 22), key='chat', values=messages,
                     right_click_menu=['&Right', ['Delete', 'Favourite', 'Reply', 'Copy', 'Edit']])],
        [gui.InputText(key='input', size=(25, 10)), gui.Button('Send', bind_return_key=True, size=(9, 1))]
    ]
```

but its not quite what I am looking for. I want: if I right click on a box in the list box, said box will be selected and the actions of that menu will affect only that box. Lets say I right click on the middle box and press delete, the middle box will be deleted. I know how to work with the event of clicking the menu, but as of right now I have no way of actually telling which message was clicked.

Comment: better create minimal working code which we could simple copy and use for testing solutions.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but need tkinter code and hack PySimleGUI code.
Here new callback for Button 3, but selection for nearest one, not exact the one. Maybe `sg.Table` or `sg.Tree` can achieve better selection.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def RightClickMenuCallback(event, element):
    widget = element.Widget
    current = widget.curselection()
    if current:
        widget.selection_clear(current[0])
    index = widget.nearest(event.y)
    widget.selection_set(index)
    element.TKRightClickMenu.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root, 0)
    element.TKRightClickMenu.grab_release()

messages = [
    'This is the start of your chat!',
    'demo messages',
    'dont know what to right',
]

command = ['Delete', 'Favourite', 'Reply', 'Copy', 'Edit']
layout = [
    [sg.Listbox(size=(35, 22), key='chat', values=messages,
        right_click_menu=['&Right', command])],
    [sg.InputText(key='input', size=(25, 10)),
     sg.Button('Send', bind_return_key=True, size=(9, 1))],
]
window = sg.Window("Test", layout, finalize=True)
chat = window['chat']
chat.Widget.bind('<Button-3>', lambda event,
    element=chat: RightClickMenuCallback(event, element))

while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    print(event, values)

window.close()
```

[Edit]

IMO, follow the way provided by library should be preferred.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

messages = [
    'This is the start of your chat!',
    'demo messages',
    'dont know what to right',
]

command = ['Delete', 'Favourite', 'Reply', 'Copy', 'Edit']
cmd_layout = [[sg.Button(cmd, size=(10, 1))] for cmd in command]
layout = [
    [sg.Listbox(values=messages, size=(35, 22), key='chat'),
     sg.Column(cmd_layout)],
    [sg.InputText(key='input', size=(25, 10)),
     sg.Button('Send', bind_return_key=True, size=(9, 1))],
]
window = sg.Window("Test", layout, finalize=True)
window['input'].expand(expand_x=True)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    print(event, values)

window.close()
```

Add option `enable_events=True` to `sg.Listbox` if you need event generated when mouse button 1 clicked. When any event generated, you can get the list of items currently selected in this listbox by `values['chat']` or `window['chat'].get()`, now there's only one item selected, so message is `values['chat'][0]`.

If you need index, you have to call `window['chat'].get_indexes()`, it returns the items currently selected as a list of indexes. So, the same, get index of selected item by `window['chat'].get_indexes()[0]`

Comment: Hey, thank you for your help. Is there a way to get both the message itself and its index? i dont really understand the code inside the function....

Comment: i dont understand how that will give me the index of the box the user had right clicked on....

Comment: `event.y` give the position of mouse when event, right click, generated. Method `nearest(y)` return the index of the visible line closest to the y-coordinate y relative to the listbox widget.

Comment: Hey again, sorry to bother you but i still can't wrap my mind around it, as im quite new to pysimplegui. i want to get in the values, {'chat': message and index} in any way possible but i cant figure out how the calling of the function works so i dont know how to do this...

Comment: Thank you @JasonYang! I had an image viewer with dozen `PySimpleGUI.Image` objects inside - with each image has `right_click_menu` defined so it could be opened using matplotlib, I couldn't find a way to get the key of the image which generated the context menu. Your example code is very helpful.!